# Artifacts on webpage found on Safari browser but not Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, safari

When I look on Google Chrome for my webapp, which is a Todo List, the styling is consistent and does not create random lines. I only noticed weird "artifacts" when I went on an Apple device and noticed that there are small lines around my text. I will link the website, and will also provide my CSS and HTML code below. I would like to know how I can edit my code so that artifacts do not appear on Safari Browsers. Here is my link, feel free to add tasks to visualize: https://todolist--ibrahimshah.repl.co/

```css
h1{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

body{
  display:flex;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #743ad5, #d53a9d);

 
}

.text{
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #743ad5, #d53a9d);
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  font-size:5vh;
  font-weight:700;
 
}
.header{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  padding:1vw;
}


#nav{
  width:100vw;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:1.25vw;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(to left, #743ad5, #d53a9d);
  border-image-slice:3;
  background:white;

}

#idk{
  position:absolute;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  
  height:70vh;
  width:35vw;
  background:white;
  left:50vw;
  top:55vh;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);

}

#innerText{
  position:absolute;
  top:3vh;
  display:inline;
}

#inputField{
  

}

#bullets{
  position:absolute;
  top:40vh;
}

.smallText{
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #743ad5, #d53a9d);
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  font-size:3vh;
  font-weight:700;

}



#input{
  border-top: 0.25vw;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(to left, #743ad5, #d53a9d);
  border-width: 0.25vw;
  border-image-slice: 1;
  border-right-style:none;
  border-left-style:none;
  width:20vw;
  height:2vh;
  
}

#inputArea{
  top:15vh;
  position:absolute;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center; 
  justify-content:center;

  width:35vw;
  height:5vh;
}

ul{
  
}


#submitButton{
  text-decoration:none;
  right:1.5vw;
  position:absolute;
  width:5vw;
  height:4vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #743ad5, #d53a9d);
  color:white;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  border-radius:1vw;
  font-weight:700;
  font-size:2vh;


}

#listArea{
  position:absolute;
  top: 25vh;
  width:25vw;
  height:35vh;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:0.75vw;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(to left, #743ad5, #d53a9d);
  border-image-slice:3;
  background:white;
  font-size:2vh;
}

.newLists{
  display:flex;
  font-size:2vh;
  height:33vh;

}
#listArea{
  overflow:scroll;
}

.btn{
  text-decoration:none;
  width:4.5vw;
  height:3.5vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #743ad5, #d53a9d);
    -webkit-text-fill-color: white;

  color:white;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  border-radius:1vw;
  font-weight:700;
  font-size:1.75vh;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  


}

.textList{
  margin-top:2vh;
  margin-bottom:2vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #743ad5, #d53a9d);
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  font-size:2vh;
  font-weight:700;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@400;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>Todo List</title>
        <link href="/views/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="nav">
            <div class="header"><div class="text">To-do List Webapp</div></div>
        </div>

        <div id="idk">
            <div id="innerText" class="text" >Tasks:</div>
            
            <div id="inputArea">
                <form>
                    <input required type="text" id="input"><input type="submit" id="submitButton" onclick="returnTask()">
                </form>
            </div>
            
            <div id="listArea">
                <ul id="divArea">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="/views/script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```